# Regex: how to extract and replace multiple instances from a string?

Tags: javascript, regex

From the string

```
"Hi @[Bob](1234) and @[John](8888)!"
```

I want to return:

```
Hi <a href="/1234">Bob</a> and <a href="/8888">John</a>!
```

I'm using JavaScript

I tried:

```
myString.replaceAll(/@\[/gim, '<a href="????">')
```

to remove unwanted characters, such as "@[" but I don't know how to extract "Bob" and "1234" from the original string to then put them back into the returned string. How to take "1234" and place it where "????" is?

Comment: When you tried to solve this problem how far did you get, what problems did you encounter, what errors were reported? Where’s your “*[mcve]*” code that reproduces your problem?

Comment: I tried .replaceAll() and yes, I can replace "@[" with "" but I don't know how to extract "Bob" from the string and put it back into the returned string.

Comment: Please show us the code you have so that we can show you what missed.

Comment: @Skeeve I added some code in the example but that's as far as I can go. All the examples I found, show how to replace 1 piece of string with another string, not with a variable that comes from the original string.

Comment: Then you need to learn about "capturing groups". There should be plenty of examples.  e.g. https://sodocumentation.net/regex/topic/660/capture-groups

Comment: See [RegExr](https://regexr.com/) for testing regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need capturing groups as in

```
@\[([^\]\[]+)\]\(([^()]+)\)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/sraJHT/1).

---

IN `JS` this could be:

```js
let some_text = "Hi @[Bob](1234) and @[John](8888)!";
some_text = some_text.replace(/@\[([^\]\[]+)\]\(([^()]+)\)/g, "<a href=\"/$2\">$1</a>");
console.log(some_text);
```

Comment: This needs to include referencing the right capture groups to put into the anchor

Comment: @TrevorKropp: Well, it does.

Comment: $1 and $2 is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @trs: Glad to help. These references are called capturing groups.